# Building a jQuery flashcard app, using array to store questions and answers

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have managed to build a rudimentary flashcard app using the following code:

```
    var currentpage, preventpage;

$(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function(event){ 
preventspin()
if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
{    
    var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists

    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
    }
    event.handled = true;
}
return false;         
});

//swiperight event
$(document).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function(event){ 
preventspin()    
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
{      
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
    }
    event.handled = true;
return false;        });

});



$(document).on("tap", ".card", function (event){
  if (preventpage == 0) {
   currentpage = $(this).parent().attr("id");

//create the info card and display it   
$("body").append('<div data-role="page" id="infocard"><div class="infocard">        <a class="info-card">This is info for '+currentpage+' Tap again to flip the card back</a></div></div>');
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#infocard", { transition: "flip"}) 
  }  
});

//tap event for info card. goes back to the card
$(document).on("tap", ".infocard", function (event){
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#"+currentpage, { transition: "flip", reverse: true })
setTimeout(function() {
$("#infocard").remove()
}, 500);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/inthevidual/kLyxped4/

I have managed to implement basic swipe-to-browse and tap-to-flip functionality, but I would like to store questions and answers in an array, instead of having them as static HTML. As you can  see, the flipside of all cards is one static set of data, and I would like this too as an array, moving through both arrays on swipe, so that I get:

front: question1, question2 etc.
flipside: answer1, answer2 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better array would be 
`[{q: question1 , a:answer1}, {q:question2, a:answer2}...]`

You already are storing an index , `currentpage`, use that to get to the specific data in the array and show it accordingly. You should be able to access the object properties -

`question = data.q`

`answer = data.a`

Comment: Oh yes of course, thank you for poiniting that out. As you might understand from the above, my knowledge of the subject and methods is quite limited. Would you mind  spelling it out to me more clearly, how to create the array and access/browse through the data within the current setup? :)

Comment: Well the array would be created in this way according to your questions and answers, generally from Database where you have this saved.

In your current setup, set a index as 0 ( first element), and manipulate it accordingly as the user does the action. So if the user slides for next question, increment it and show the question at that index. If he taps, then show the answer at that index.

Its very basic, try and share your progress.

Comment: I understand that this is very basic, but so is my understanding of jQuery.
Could you please illustrate, perhaps in a jsfiddle, how I can create an index, include this array in it and manipulate it on swiperight, swipeleft, and/or tap?

Comment: Sorry @inthevidual, cant spoon feed answers to you. Try and share your progress.